# automatic add centavos in money value (12,345.00 , 12,345.55) in textbox asp.net from user input

Tags: java, regex, textbox, money-format

I have this code that works fine when it comes to comma money place value. User types in and it automatically adds a comma (12,345). here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function Comma(Num) {
        Num += '';
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        x = Num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1))
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        return x1 + x2;
    }

</script>
```

But what I want to happen is to add a .00 at the end of the currency value. (12,345.00) any tricks or reference you might want to share?

UPDATE
[typed in 1, two zeroes become visible. then i typed in another 1's, it goes after the zeroes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQQWg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : ''; --> 
x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '**.00**';

```
function Comma(Num) {
    while (Num.indexOf(',')>=0)
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); 
    x = Num.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + (x[1]+'00').substring(0, 2) : '.00';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: Replace x[1] with (x[1]+'00').substring(0, 2) to handle all cases :  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + (x[1]+'00').substring(0, 2) : '.00';

Comment: can you please update your answer sir. please and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery FormatCurrency plugin:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

Comment: just download? then?